# Can't find Configure.exe in my QT-installation

Tags: qt

I'm using the latest QT SDK (RC 1.1) on Windows but can't find the Configure.exe

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the source code package. All the SDKs are pre-build binaries that do not contain tools to build Qt.